# How can you disable KDE notification sounds in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, okular

I installed Okular pdf viewer in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Okular is a KDE based software and it emits a KDE notification sound when I do some actions for example when I overwrite a file.

Is it possible that I disable these KDE notifications sounds and how do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

I run Ubuntustudio 15.10, and have installed the KDE-app Kolourpaint.
Wonderful app, but the sounds ... terrible.

1. Open File Manager and enable "View Hidden Files"
2. Go to FileSystem/usr/share
3. Open a terminal there and type
4. sudo chmod -R 777 sounds
5. Open FileSystem/usr/share/sounds in the File Manager
6. Delete every KDE*.ogg file.

Now no more KDE system sounds will disturb you.

Comment: Not really the best solution. Deleting system files isn't what we call "safe," and providing an iffy workaround for the question isn't what we call "an answer."

Comment: THANK YOU! Perfect solution - at least this one works. I am running KMail under Xfce (no KDE) and these notification sounds were driving me nuts. Thank you!!!

Comment: After trying the other solutions, which didn't work because they are out of date, this is what i did too. They are just sound files being deleted, i am not concerned about any unforeseen impact.

Answer (score 0):

If you have KDE installed you disable sounds using systemsettings
https://falsecolour.com/aw/computer/okularsounds/index.html

If you don't have full KDE, then you might be out of luck, I don't know.

Edit: you can try this in the second case:
https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/okular-devel/2012-January/010986.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are hearing is not okular's sounds, but KDE notification sounds. The best way to manage those is to install systemsettings: `sudo apt-get install systemsettings`

I did not want to have any sounds, so I switched them completely off: 
run systemtettings => Application and System Notifications => Player Settings => No audio Output.

Source: https://superuser.com/a/281242/334492

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed](https://superuser.com/questions/280880/disable-kde-sounds-in-gnome-ubuntu/281242) by saaj, this works for me nicely, a) without installing anything extra nor b) deleting files and breaking the system:

```
kcmshell4 kcmnotify
```

Then select *Player Settings* and choose *No audio output*.