# How can I disable KDE sounds in Xfce (Vivid)? Or: Why is systemsettings empty?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, kde, xfce

I'm running Xubuntu 15.04 (vivid), and have a few KDE apps installed (kdevelop, konqueror). I would like to disable their notification sounds.

I know that this issue has been [discussed before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454772/how-can-you-disable-kde-notification-sounds-in-ubuntu-14-04), and that KDE behaviour is usually managed through `systemsettings`. I have installed the package, unfortunately there's only one entry, `Appearance → Application style`.

So the question would be: How do I get the entry for managing the sounds? Or is there another way to disable the notification sounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, apparently the systemsettings shipped by (X)Ubuntu 15.04 is for KDE 5. This means that control center modules for KDE 4 don't show up there.

They can be loaded through the `kcmshell4` command. In my case, it was

```
kcmshell4 kcmnotify
```

Then go to “Player settings” → “No audio output”.

Silence.